# Смысловые пропорции (математическая лингвистика)

Tags: математика, недопустимая-метка

Математическая лингвистика, являясь разделом лингвистики, требует хорошей формальной логики. Попробуйте решить эти смысловые пропорции, т.е. найти в каждом пункте X и Y.
Задание создано "по мотивам" сборников задач лингвистических олимпиад.

1. встать: заснуть : X : родиться = стоять: спать: гореть: Y;
2. проснуться: погаснуть: умереть: встать = усыпить: X: Y: посадить;
3. заснуть: разбудить: X = родиться: Y: мертвый.
4. бояться: ниже: выиграть: дружить: X = страшить: выше: проиграть: Y: повиноваться.

*То же помещу к математикам. Кто ответит лучше? ;-))*

Комментарий - подсказка к п. 4. Если считать, что левое и правое - это антонимы, то почему слову "бояться" соответствует "страшить"? Антонимом к нему будет "не бояться", "быть смелым" (с некоторой натяжкой)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**проснуться: погаснуть : умереть: встать = усыпить : X : Y: посадить;**

X=зажигать; Y=оживить

Comment: Почему зажигать, а не зажечь?
В таких задачах это принципиально.

Comment: Я не знаю русский язык на столько глубоко, чтобы дать грамотно свое объяснение. Приведенный мной пример - это наитие.

Попробую объясниться.

проснуться - усыпить
погаснуть - ЗАЖИГАТЬ (в вашем варианте ЗАЖЕЧЬ)
умереть - ОЖИВИТЬ
встать - посадить

Сути вроде эти два слова ЗАЖИГАТЬ и ЗАЖЕЧЬ не меняют. Но ЗАЖИГАТЬ на фоне всех этих "-ТЬ" сюда вписывается, с моей точки зрения, более гармонично.

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно.
Я не требовал от вас объяснения, просто спрашивал, случайно ли вы написали зажигать вместо зажечь. Все гдаголы - совершенного вида (отвечают на вопрос - что сделать?), а ваш вариант "зажигать" - несовршенного (что делать?). Вот я и спросил.

Comment: В таком случае - ЗАПАЛИТЬ

Answer (score 1):

1. встать: заснуть: **зажечь(ся)**: родиться = стоять: спать: гореть: жить (существовать);
2. проснуться: погаснуть: умереть: встать = усыпить: **зажечь: родить:** посадить;
3. заснуть: разбудить: **убитый** = родиться: **заснуть**: мертвый;
4. бояться: ниже: выиграть: дружить: **властвовать (приказывать)** = страшить: выше: проиграть: **враждовать:** повиноваться

Comment: Третий ответ у вас неправильный. В остальных - нечеткости, хотя тут действительно некачественная формулировка.

Зажечь (без -ся) не пойдёт. У остальных глаголов нет каузативности 
Родить - плохо. Точный антоним к "умирать" - оживать, не "рождаться". 
в первой части семантика "сон/спать", не "убитый/мертвый" 
властвовать и приказывать - очень слабые антонимы к "повиноваться". Впрочем, "хорошего" решения всё равно нет.

Comment: "Тонкости" вроде родиться-ожить можно и опустить, считая оба ответа правильными (на том уровне точности, который допускает постановка задачи). Но вот четвертый пункт решен __в корне__ неверно! Это не антонимы (тут есть подвох). Впрочем, математики тоже пока не догадались.

Comment: Простите, а кто определяет "уровень точности"? Если автор вопроса, то источник четвертого пункта - явно не тот, что предыдущих. 
Может, вы просто не из той кладовки этот четвертый пункт позаимствовали.
Точный антоним к бояться - "не бояться", но такой случай именно за "уровнем точности". А пугать/страшить - вполне приемлемый пароним.

Comment: В общем понятно. 
Дружить-дружить; повиноваться-властвовать(держать в подчинении).
Я даже опускаю сомнительную вторую пару, но перваю - ни в какие ворота не лезет. Остальные пары - все-таки соответствуют инверсии  субъекта-объекта действия, а в русском языке дружат, увы, с кем, а не кого.  

В оригинале эта задача ещё более или менее решабельна, там это "дружить-дружить" в условии, хотя тоже не слишком удачна, по причине уже сказанной.

Но ваш вариант - только гуглом. Ну или с вашими подсказками. Зря вы (или кто там) перевели на "пропроции". Это немного другой стиль лингвистических задач.

Answer (score 1):

**Лучше** бы ответили вы.
Вы сами-то ответы проверяли? Или хотя бы знаете? 
Уж больно неоднозначен выбор, особенно в четвертой задече, точного антонима к "повиноваться" нет.  
А во второй надо бы "уложить", а не посадить.

**встать: заснуть : X : родиться = стоять: спать: гореть: Y;**
X=зажечься (загореться); Y=жить

**проснуться: погаснуть : умереть: встать = усыпить : X : Y: посадить;**
X=зажечь; Y=оживить

**заснуть: разбудить: X = родиться: Y: мертвый.** 
X=бодрствующий; Y=убить

**бояться: ниже: выиграть: дружить: X = страшить: выше: проиграть: Y: повиноваться.**
X=неповиноваться (повелевать?); Y=враждовать

Comment: п. 1-3 хорошо. К п. 4 см. добавление в вопросе.

Comment: В общем понятно. Дружить-дружить; повиноваться-властвовать(держать в подчинении). Я даже опускаю сомнительную вторую пару, но перваю - ни в какие ворота не лезет. Остальные пары - все-таки соответствуют инверсии субъекта-объекта действия, а в русском языке дружат, увы, с кем, а не кого.
В оригинале эта задача ещё более или менее решабельна, там это "дружить-дружить" в условии, хотя тоже не слишком удачна, по причине уже сказанной.
Но ваш вариант - только гуглом. Ну или с вашими подсказками. Зря вы (или кто там) перевели на "пропроции". Это немного другой стиль лингвистических задач.

Comment: Чувствуется глубокий логик! Да, последняя задача добавлена искуственно!